# Sort millions of text files in a folder using unix sort

Tags: 12.04, sort

I am trying to sort a lot of files (millions ie approx 2.5m) .txt files in a folder called NZParsed.

All the files in the folder are named like 1.txt 2.txt and so on till 25xxxxx.txt

After running the following command in eclipse :

```
os.system("sort -k1,1 -k3,3n -k4,4n -y 1048576 /home/viraj/NZ/NZParsed/* -o /home/viraj/NZ/SplitIndex/abcd.txt")
```

I get an error:

```
sh: 1: sort: Argument list too long
```

Can anyone tell me any other way I could sort all these files into 1 file and split them using the following command in eclipse:

```
os.system("split -C 200m /home/viraj/NZ/SplitIndex/abcd.txt /home/viraj/NZ/SplitIndex/")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with eclipse or python. You are hitting the ARG_MAX limit, for more details see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/110282/22222) but briefly, this is the limit of how many bytes the list of arguments to a command can be.

So, to avoid this, you need to `sort` in a way that does not list the files. For example:

```
for i in /home/viraj/NZ/NZParsed/*; do cat "$i" ; done |
    sort -k1,1 -k3,3n -k4,4n -y 1048576 > /home/viraj/NZ/SplitIndex/abcd.txt
```

The command above will `cat` each file and then pass the contents of all files through your `sort` command. That way, the files are never listed and you won't have the `ARG_MAX` problem.

Another approach would be to use find's `-exec` option:

```
find /home/viraj/NZ/NZParsed/ -type f -name '[0-9]*.txt' -exec cat {} + | 
    sort -k1,1 -k3,3n -k4,4n -y 1048576 > /home/viraj/NZ/SplitIndex/abcd.txt
```

Comment: I am getting the same error when using the find's exec command.

Comment: @Viraj that's because I'm an idiot and had a syntax error. There should be no `*` in the `find`. Try with the updated answer.

Comment: @Viraj did it work?

Comment: Yes. It seems to be working. No error as of yet. Also for the find command do we need to add -type f because I get the error cat: /home/viraj/NZ/NZParsed/ Is a directory ?. Cant upvote because of lack of reputation but Thank you.

Comment: @Viraj yes, sorry, I assumed you wanted to sort everything. See updated answer for a more precise `find` command.